# Validation issue?

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm pulling out my hair! I am working on a webstore that sells electronic gift certificates and but also allows check and paypal sales. I am trying to write a script to throw an alert and not allow a form to process **IF** both the sku field ends in the word "GIFT" **AND** the payment method is set to "check" or "paypal"

Here is the field that generates the SKU & the one where the payment method are

```
<td><a href="<CGIURL>/category.cgi?item=<SKU>" id="sku" name="sku"><SKU></a></td>


<td name="payment">
<h5>Using the following payment:</h5>
<p>Check/Money Order</p>
```

I can't even get the form to validate the sku field let alone test for both variables to be true!! Might have got in over my head on this one.

```
<script language="javascript">
function checkGC() {
var GC = document.getElementById('sku');
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+GIFT/;
if (filter.test(GC.value)) {
alert('Please provide an alternate payment method');
GC.focus;
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

Any suggestions or advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nitpick: You don't throw alerts, you show them.  An alert is not an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if(filter.test(GC.value))
```

to:

```
if(/GIFT$/.test(GC.value)) // ends with GIFT
```

simplest way to check for "ends with"...

and fix the bug:

```
GC.focus;
```

to:

```
GC.focus();
```